# How to count tickets with status change filtered byYear-To-Date in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 snapshots of data set stored in 2 dataframes that contains JIRA tickets, there is a column called  **UpdatedDate** which tells me when the snapshot was taken.
I want to calculate number of tickets which still remain open filter by Year-to-Date which basically means: how many tickets in total (combined snapshots) are still open util tomorrow (eg.2019-03-29).

But the problem is the both of my dataframes can contain the same JIRA issue, but the **status** of the ticket **might** or **might not** change.

```
# this df1 (Snapshot 1)
Issue key   Project name    Status   UpdatedDate
111         Proj1          Analysis   2019-03-18
222         Proj1          Open       2019-03-18

# this df2 (Snapshot 2)
Issue key   Project name    Status   UpdatedDate
111         Proj1          Done      2019-03-28
222         Proj1          Open      2019-03-28
```

So as the table indicated above, issue111's status has changed to **Done** on snapshot 2 where as issue222's status is still **Open**. 
So if my Year-to-Date filter is set on 2019-03-29. it will show me 2 ticket with Status **Open**, but one of them will be a duplication.

How can I count number of ticket that are still open but without duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

you can `sort_values()` and then `drop_duplicates()`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]) \
  .sort_values(['UpdatedDate'], ascending=[False]) \
  .drop_duplicates(['Issue key'], keep='first') \
  .loc[lambda x: x.Status == 'Open']
```